# QT painting rich text on QGraphicsScene

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, rich-text-editor, richtext

I am writing very simple vector tool for graphics. I have rich text edited in `QTextEditor`. I also have class extending `QGraphicsScene` where all my drawings are. I want to somehow paint text from `QTextEditor` on this scene? What are my options?

Best Regards!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`QPainter::drawtext()`](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qpainter.html#drawText) method. basically you get a painter of the area you want to draw in and then use this method to draw your text.

```
 QPainter p(this);
 p.drawText(rect(), Qt::AlignCenter, "Hello World!");
```

Comment: Interesting, and I see drawtext() accepts QTextOption as argument besides QString. However, could I get all text blocks from QTextEdit or QTextDocument and their QTextOptions and sequentialy paint them with same painter...?

Comment: Yes I think so, you just have to create it once (I usually use it only inside `paintEvent`) bind it to the widget , and use it to do all the drawing on the widget.